# Use of BITMAPS column in hive BITMAP index table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

The Hive BITMAP index table contains the four columns (id, _bucketname, _offset, _bitmaps) whereas all columns are self explanatory except the last one.

I read the BITMAP(wiki) indexing and according to it, the bitmaps column contains two Boolean values(1,0) but in hive i see big numbers(binary and decimals) and i am not able to understand how it works.

Could anyone please explain how the last column(_bitmaps) helps in Indexing and usage of it internally?

Answer (score -2):

it tells you at which position the bit is set or not, thats the number you see. So its like 145638th bit is set. So you end up using much less space than representing the number as integer.